# Convert string date AM/PM to date format with structure ""%d-%Y-%m %I:%M:%S %p" in R

Tags: r, lubridate

I have some string dates that are in the following format:

```
dates <- c("12-2020-01 01:01:29 PM", "12-2020-01 01:01:40 PM", "12-2020-01 02:01:47 PM")
```

I tried with:

```
 as.POSIXct(dates, format="%d-%Y-%m %I:%M:%S %p") # return NA
```

also with:

```
a$INICIO_EVENTO <- strptime(a$INICIO_EVENTO, "%d-%Y-%m %I:%M:%S %p")
```

How can I convert the dates into a date format?

Comment: It could be an issue on your locale because it si working for me `as.POSIXct(dates, format="%d-%Y-%m %I:%M:%S %p")
[1] "2020-01-12 13:01:29 EST" "2020-01-12 13:01:40 EST" "2020-01-12 14:01:47 EST"`

Comment: The following with package `lubridate` will work: `parse_date_time(dates, '%m/%Y/%d %I:%M:%S %p')`. You can also specifiy the timezone by adding `tz = "America/New_York"` for instance.

Comment: I]t woirked the second way. thanks I'll check my locale!